# DBIx to JSON - Wrong format

Tags: json, perl, catalyst, dbix-class

In a **Catalyst** application, I need to generate **JSON** from **DBIx::Class:Core** objects.

Such a class definition looks like this:

```
use utf8;
package My::Schema::Book;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Moose;
use MooseX::NonMoose;
use MooseX::MarkAsMethods autoclean => 1;
extends 'DBIx::Class::Core';

__PACKAGE__->load_components("InflateColumn::DateTime");
__PACKAGE__->table("books");
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  "id",
  {
    data_type => "uuid",
    default_value => \"uuid_generate_v4()",
    is_nullable => 0,
    size => 16,
  },
  "title"
);
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key("id");

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

sub TO_JSON {
    my $self = shift;
    {book => {
        id => $self->id,
        title => $self->title,
    }}
}

1;
```

After queriyng the books from database I do the encoding of the blessed objects:

```
$c->stash(books_rs => $c->model('My::Schema::Book'));
$c->stash(books => [$c->stash->{books_rs}->search(
    {},
    {order_by => 'title ASC'})]
);
$c->stash(json => $json->convert_blessed->encode($c->stash->{books}));
$c->forward('View::JSON');
```

The JSON output of the query is this:

```
{"json":"[{\"book\":{\"id\":\"ae355346-8e19-46ee-88ee-773ac30938a9\",\"title\":\"TITLE1\"}},{\"book\":{\"id\":\"9a20f526-d4cd-4e7d-a726-55e78bc3c0ac\",\"title\":\"TITLE2\"}},{\"book\":{\"title\":\"TITLE3\",\"id\":\"1ddb2d27-3ec6-46c1-a1a7-0b151fe44597\"}}]"}
```

The value of the **json** key and each particular book key got double quotes what can not be parsed by jQuery. It complains about format exception.

Comment: I think you are double-encoding your data. It seems that the other methods (either "stash" or "forward", I don't know your specific framework) are encoding the whole object for you, yet you have already encoded the data within it yourself. So what it does is take your encoded string of the "blessed" objects, and wrap it in another JSON object which has the single property "json" within it, containing your string. To fix is I would expect you can simply write `$c->stash(json => $c->stash->{books});` without the manual encoding.

Comment: (I'm not writing as answer as I don't know your framework, so I'm not totally certain, I just came to this question through the json tag. But it seems logical. So if it works please confirm and I'll write as a full answer. Thanks).

Comment: Is this the default View::JSON? Shouldn't that sort of eat the `json` stash key and produce only the data structure behind that key as the output?

Comment: Yes, it is the default Catalyst::View::JSON, but there is no sub at all.

Comment: And the configuration of View::JSON is 'View::JSON' => { allow_callback  => 1, callback_param  => 'cb', expose_stash    => [ qw(json) ], json_encoder_args => +{utf8=>0}, }

Comment: @ADyson - the indicated assignment of the result set of books to the stash doesn't work.

Comment: @KérdezösködőIndián "doesn't work" means what exactly? What does your output look like now? What problem are you experiencing now?

Answer (score 1):

`$json->convert_blessed->encode($c->stash->{books})` returns a string. It looks like `View::JSON` also encodes json.

Try to pass your data as is: `$c->stash(json => $c->stash->{books});`. You may also need to configure `expose_stash` and `json_encoder_args` to handle the right keys from your stash and correctly convert your objects.

See
https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::View::JSON#CONFIG-VARIABLES